# INNER JOIN from the same table

Tags: sql, select, inner-join

I need to make a inner join of two queries in a mysql same table "ride":

```
id| appointment_address|arrival_city| arrival_country|departure_city|departure_country|end_date|nb_places|price|start_date|travel_id|rank
```

The first query :

```
SELECT DISTINCT travel_id FROM ride  WHERE departure_city LIKE <value> AND start_date > <value> OR departure_country LIKE <value> AND start_date > <value>;
```

The second one

```
SELECT DISTINCT travel_id FROM ride  WHERE arrival_city LIKE <value2> AND start_date > <value> OR departure_country LIKE <value2> AND start_date > <value>;
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it as below.

```
select * 
from (SELECT DISTINCT travel_id FROM ride  WHERE departure_city LIKE <value> AND start_date > <value> OR departure_country LIKE <value> AND start_date > <value>) firstQuery

Join 
(SELECT DISTINCT travel_id FROM ride  WHERE arrival_city LIKE <value2> AND start_date > <value> OR departure_country LIKE <value2> AND start_date > <value>) secondQuery on firstQuery.<field_to_join > = secondQuery.<field_to_join >
```